# How to put a file text into a two dimensional array in bash or python

Tags: linux

I am working on a bash script and so far this is what I want to do;

Let's say that i have a file.txt

This Is

The File

Text That

I Am

Referring To

I want to make my script to print out using a variable the first column

This

The

Text

I

Referring

Also another variable to print the second column

Is

File

That

Am

To

I want to put the two different output into an array so I can call it whenever I want

Can you please help me?

Comment: Is it important that there are blanck lines inbetween?

Answer (score 1):

For a file `sample.txt`

```
This Is
The File
Text That
I Am
Referring To
```

the command

`$ cut -d' ' -f1 sample.txt`

outputs the following to the standard output.

```
This
The
Text
I
Referring
```

and the command (with `-f2`)

`$ cut -d' ' -f2 sample.txt`

outputs the following

```
Is
File
That
Am
To
```

Maybe you can modify them to store the result to an array.

---

With python, you can get a 'list of list' which may be used somewhat like a 2D array as following

```
nice_list=[line.split() for line in open('sample.txt','r')]
```

For example, the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fname='sample.txt'
nice_list=[line.split() for line in open(fname,'r')] 

numrow=len(nice_list)

print '----------------'
print 'first column:'
for jrow in range(numrow):
    print nice_list[jrow][0]

print '----------------'
print 'second column:'
for jrow in range(numrow):
    print nice_list[jrow][1]
```

outputs

```
----------------
first column:
This
The
Text
I
Referring
----------------
second column:
Is
File
That
Am
To
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. That is very helpful. I will just have to write my script in Python then. The idea behind that question is to have a cript the will create a logrotate file in the /etc/logrotate.d for if there is any log rotate  files created. I will post another question so you can have an idea of what I am talking about